# If $G : \mathcal{D} \to \mathcal{C}$ has a left adjoint then $G$ preserves kernels.

Tags: category-theory, adjoint-functors

The theorem 7.7 in Course an homologic algebra of Peter Hilton is

*If $G: \mathcal{D} \to \mathcal{C}$ has a left adjoint then G preserves products,
pull-backs and kernels.*

Hilton prove that $G$ prerserves products and pull backs and leave the proof that $G$ preserv kernel as exercise. How can I prove that $ G $ preserves the kernel? There are some demonstrations with notions of limits and colimites, but they are notions that are not used in the book. I want to try it without using the concepts of limits and colimites. How can I do it?

Comment: You can define kernels in terms of pullbacks and products, so, other than demonstrating this, you're done. That said, it's actually pretty straightforward to prove that right adjoints preserve all limits. The proofs given for products and pullbacks presumably look similar and there would be a similar proof for kernels since they are likely all the same proof just instantiated differently.

Answer (score 1):

$\mathcal{C}$ and $\mathcal{D}$ should admit zero object. Let $\eta: F \dashv G$.

We are going to show two things:

1. $G$ preserves zero objects hence zero morphisms.
2. $G$ preserves equalizers, i.e. if $f$ is the equalizer of $\varphi_1$ and $\varphi_2$ then $Gf$ is the equalizer of $G\varphi_1$ and $G\varphi_2$.

It's easy to see that $f$ is the kernel of $\varphi$ iff $f$ is the equalizer of $0$ and $\varphi$. Then the original statement is proved.

---

Proof of 1.

Let $Z$ be the zero object in $\mathcal{D}$ and $N$ an object in $\mathcal{C}$. Since $\eta : Hom(FN,Z) \rightarrow Hom(N,GZ)$ is bijective, $\left| Hom(N,GZ)\right| = \left| Hom(FN,Z)\right| = 1$. Therefore $GZ$ is terminal object hence zero object. It immediately follows that $G$ preserves zero morphisms.

---

Proof of 2.

Let $f$ be the equalizer of $\varphi_1$ and $\varphi_2$. For any $\tau$ such that $G\varphi_1 \circ  \tau = G\varphi_2 \circ \tau$, we have $\varphi_1 \circ \eta^{-1}\tau = \varphi_2 \circ \eta^{-1}\tau$ by naturality of $\eta^{-1}$. So there is a unique morhism $\tau_0$ such that $f \circ \tau_0 = \eta^{-1}\tau$. Again, by bijectivity and naturality of $\eta$, $\eta\tau_0$ is the unique morphism such that $Gf \circ \eta\tau_0 = \tau$, so $Gf$ is the equalizer of $G\varphi_1$ and $G\varphi_2$.